# How to call a method on starting touch/drag in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, drag-and-drop

I used https://github.com/fatlinesofcode/ngDraggable for Drag&Drop in AngularJS.
It works very fine, but I need to do some operations when the user is starting with dragging. This is `myMethod()`. I implemented a `ng-mousedown`. On desktops there are no problems, but it doesn't work on touch devices.

```
 <div ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="myObject" ng-mousedown="myMethod()">
    123
 </div>
```

Any ideas?

Comment: Didi you try to use `ngTouch` , `ngSwipeLeft`  or `ngSwipeRight` module ? take a look [here](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch)

Comment: Yes, I tried it. ngTouch only has three directives. ngClick, ngSwipeLeft and ngSwipeRight (https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngTouch).

Answer (score 0):

For all who have the same problem:

I used the $swipe service of the ngTouch module. The given div is now a directive. On dragging myMethod() is called.

HTML:

```
<my-directive ng-drag="true" ng-drag-data="myObject" on-drag="myMethod()"></my-directive>
```

Directive:

```
angular.module('myApp')
.directive('myDirective', ['$swipe',
  function($swipe) {

    return {
      restrict: 'EA',
      scope: {
        onDrag: '&'
      },
      link: function(scope, ele, attrs, ctrl) {
      $swipe.bind(ele, {
          'start': function(coords) {
            scope.onDrag();
          }
      }
    }
}]);
```